# CSS to lay out keys/values legend horizontally.

Tags: html, css

I am creating a horizontal legend in html/css. I have a colored box with some text next to it, then some space, then another colored box with some text, a space, etc.

```
[blue] - LabelA    [green] - LabelB    [red] - LabelC
```

I can't figure out how to do this cross browser. I have tried all combinations of floating divs/spans I can think of, but either the label ends up going underneath the colored box or I can't get padding to work to separate each key in the legend.

How would you do this?

Comment: It will really help if you post your closest working example so someone can assist you in finding out how to fix it.

Comment: @Whetstone I am actually more interested in seeing how someone solves this problem the best way than simply hacking my solution until it works

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need floats for this sort of thing. Really what you have is a list of pairs. There is a tag set for that called a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3):

```
<dl>
    <dt>[blue]</dt>
    <dd> - LabelA </dd>

    <dt>[green]</dt>
    <dd> - LabelB </dd>

    <dt>[red]</dt>
    <dd> - LabelC </dd>
</dl>
```

These are <strike>`inline`</strike> *`block`* by default. From there you can style the pairs of elements like so:

```
<style>
     dl
     {
         width: 200px;
         background: #fff;
         border: 1px solid #000;
         padding: 5px 15px;
      }

      dt, dd
      {
         display: inline;
      }       
</style>
```

Comment: No, they're really not. They're `block`. I agree this is the correct way to mark it up, however. You just need to realize that either `display: inline` or `float: left` will be necessary.

Answer (score 74):

Here's a simple example:

```css
/* basic positioning */
.legend { list-style: none; }
.legend li { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
.legend span { border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 12px; height: 12px; margin: 2px; }
/* your colors */
.legend .superawesome { background-color: #ff00ff; }
.legend .awesome { background-color: #00ffff; }
.legend .kindaawesome { background-color: #0000ff; }
.legend .notawesome { background-color: #000000; }
```

```html
<ul class="legend">
    <li><span class="superawesome"></span> Super Awesome</li>
    <li><span class="awesome"></span> Awesome</li>
    <li><span class="kindaawesome"></span> Kinda Awesome</li>
    <li><span class="notawesome"></span> Not Awesome</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have just to add this style to the li in your css ==> list-style-type: none;

Answer (score 3):

Based on Rob Allen answer, this is a quick and simple legend using definition lists:

dl, dt and dd are display block by default. Since we want the dt and dd to be on the same line, we use display: inline-block. (Inline block is important for us to be able to control the width and height of the colored square)

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt class="red"></dt>
    <dd>Existing clients</dd>

    <dt class="yellow"></dt>
    <dd>New clients</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl dt{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
dl dd{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
dl dt.red{
    background: #f8d7da;
}
dl dt.yellow{
    background: #f2c715;
}
```

**Result:**
[See the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r48qk.png)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use floating divs. Try this

```
DIV.LegendItem
{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:20px;
}
```

(add width and height if DIV has no content)

Sorry if your text is not in the box also add this...

```
SPAN.LegendText
{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:20px;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/m6VAr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

Avoided floats as you specifically mentioned cross browser, so I assume you are at least supporting IE7. IE7 wraps floats in kind of a nasty way which is why I suggested inline divs.

DOCTYPE HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

HTML

```
<div class="Legend">
  <div class="Blue">&nbsp;</div>
    Blue
    <div class="Green">&nbsp;</div>
    Green
    <div class="Red">&nbsp;</div>
    Red
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Legend div{
    margin-left:15px;
    width:16px;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    display:inline-block;
}
.ie7 .Legend div{
    display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
.Red {background-color:red;}
.Green {background-color:green;}
.Blue {background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a small table and using background colors.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="backgroundcolor:red; width:5px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>- Red</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables should never be used for layouts.

Comment: I your data is tabular data, then this is the best approach. If not, then you should avoid this, as it is not semantic.

Comment: Tables should not be used for "layouts", but he wasn't talking about layouts, just displaying data.  Read the question before down voting.

Comment: I would qualify a legend as tabular data, and thus a valid way to mark it up.